# CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehaviour deprecated, no other option

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, behavior

So according to [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior), `defaultBehaviour` is deprecated and `AttachedBehaviour` should be used instead.

However:

[image: attachedbehaviour]

does not "exist" in android. I always receive the `Annotation type expected` error.

My import is:
`import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;`

Am I using the wrong import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AttachedBehavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/coordinatorlayout/widget/CoordinatorLayout.AttachedBehavior) is an interface, not an annotation.

Therefore your `CustomLinearLayout` must `implement AttachedBehavior` and override the `getBehavior()` method to return an instance of your `MoveUpwardBehavior` class.